# Sumif between two dates over two columns

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, excel-2011

I would like to sum a column between two dates, however the dates are in separate columns.

I want the sum total between the following dates 01-01-2014 (cell E1) and 31-03-2014 (cell F1).

If you look at cell C6 the date is lower than the first range and is being included as you would expect.

The current formula looks at the two columns individually i.e. is Start date (column B) above E1 and then is End date (column C) below F1.

I need a formula that takes into account both dates i.e if start date is above E1 and below F1 then sum the Price column.

The date at C6 is something I would like to avoid, even though it is below cell F1 I still want it to be above cell E1.

Is anyone able to lend some assistance on how I could do this?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=SUMIFS(E:E,B:B,">="&E1,C:C,">"&E1,C:C,"<="&F1)
```