# Using a Sumifs formula

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to sum all cash lodgements made by a specific customer during a particular quarter (i.e Q1, Q2, Q3 ..) the date is in the following format mm/dd/yyyy.

```
=SUMIFS (lodgements, customer_id, "12345", date_Lodged, ">=cell_reference_1",date_lodged,"<=cell_reference_2")
```

**cell_reference_1** = reference to a cell with the date of the beginning of that quarter (04/01/2019)

**cell_reference_2** = reference to a cell with the date of the end of that quarter (06/30/2019)

Both date_lodged and cell_references are formatted as Date values.

I am getting to values from my sumifs formula even though they are lodgements in each quarter.

Comment: Some sample data would make this easier to answer, but try `">="&cell_reference_1` and `"<="&cell_reference_2`.

Comment: Possible duplicate, at least very similar : https://stackoverflow.com/q/27932554/4961700

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on your formula as @BigBen mentioned on the comments. The formula should be:

```
=SUMIFS (lodgements, customer_id, "12345", date_Lodged, ">="&cell_reference_1,date_lodged,"<="&cell_reference_2)
```

You need to keep `cell_reference_1` and `cell_reference_2` as reference, if you keep them within quotation marks they won't be a reference to a cell.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Daniel If works, please accept the answer. Thanks!